# MySQL Updating enum field type vlaue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following script :

```
UPDATE employee
SET is_active='No'
WHERE employee_id = 1
```

I want to update the  is_active column which is of type enum from Yes to No, but when I try, I get a feedback of 0 rows affected with no changes made to the database.

What is the best way to update the value of field type enum?

Comment: You will get "0 rows affected" if either (a) the filter in the `WHERE` clause matches no records; or (b) no records change as a result of the `UPDATE` command.  Are you sure that there is a record with `employee_id=1` that has `is_active='Yes'`?

Comment: If you get no error, but only a message that no rows were updated, then my guess is that the column 'is_active' from the row where employee_id = 1 is already set to 'No'. Therefore no changes are needed and will not be made

Answer (score 1):

That query is working fine for me in a little test table I created...

Are you sure you have an employee with an employee_id of 1? Or that the is_active field isn't already set to 'No'? Both those scenarios would cause 0 rows to be affected.

Comment: It worked , there was a problem with the is_active field. Sorry for that